# Lambda Calculus Reduction / evaluating expressions

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

I was reading these [notes](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/papers/lambdanotes.pdf) on lambda calculus, and I am having some trouble reducing / evaluating one of the expressions at the start.

In particular the function 
(λf.λx.f(f(x)))(λy.y^2)(5).

How exactly do I begin this? He says the answer comes out to be 625. My mathematical intuition says that we proceed like so:
(λf.λx.f(f(x)))(5^2) and he said previously that f(x) is the map

x |-> x^2

so f(f(x)) is the composition which would be f o f = (f)^2 = x^4

So further reducing our lambda expression we get

(λf.λx.x^4))(5^2)

But then we would plug 25 into x^4 which gives us 25*25*25*25 = 390,625.

(λf.(390,625))

then when we get here, I have absolutely no idea what this expression represents?

What part of the Lambda Calculus have I misunderstood? Is the way I am reducing expressions correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about lambda calculus, so feel free to downvote me into oblivion if I'm wrong :) Plus my terminology will be off, so hopefully someone experienced will answer the question. This should probably be posted to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) anyways.

The

[image]

was given earlier as an example and was not meant to carry over to subsequent problems.

First of all, it looks as if you didn't copy the expression correctly. According to the PDF, it is:

[image]

Now the order of operations matters (brackets first!).

We start with:

[image]

We are providing the lambda term on the left [image] with the argument [image]. This means that f is replaced by the squared function.

So now we have:

[image]

**Edit:**

The reason why [image] is given as an argument to [image] is that we could write the whole expression as:

[image]

If we look at the first part, it's easier to see that [image] applies to the first argument:

[image]

Comment: How do we know that we are providing the argument to the left most lambda term? Can you write that operation more explicitly? 

As such, you said the argument (λy.y^2) goes to the left most term (λf.λx.f(f(x))), how would you write that in full?

Comment: From what I understand, the notation for lambda calculus leaves out extra parentheses to make it easier to read. Each function with multiple parameters can be broken down into smaller functions with single parameters and then evaluated in a process called currying. Here's a paraphrase from http://functionspace.com/articles/58/Basics-of---lambda--Calculus: "Currying is the ability using which multiple arguments can be dealt with. Basically, if a lambda function has more than 1 bound variable, we simplify this by applying the arguments one by one in the left associative manner".

Answer (score 1):

Correct normal-order (leftmost first) beta-reduction to normal form:

```
   (λ f. (λ x. f (f x))) (λ y. y ^ 2) 5
=  (λ x. (λ y. y ^ 2) ((λ y. y ^ 2) x)) 5
=  (λ x. ((λ y. y ^ 2) x) ^ 2) 5
=  (λ x. (x ^ 2) ^ 2) 5
=  (5 ^ 2) ^ 2
=  25 ^ 2
=  625
```

Numerical primitives like `2`, `5`, and `^`, though [encodable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), are not part of the grammar. Intuitive conventional algebraic reduction rules like exponent multiplication don't apply; only beta- and possibly eta-reduction.